# Lambda out of memory with pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to convert a JSON file to CSV using Lambda.
I am using Pandas for this operation.
Initially I started with the following configuration :

File Size : 5 MB

Memory : 128

It took me around 5 seconds to complete the conversion.

Then I increased the file size to 10 MB, but there is a weird behavior.
It will be great if someone could help me to understand this.
Basically I am trying to benchmark this operation
Sometimes the file is getting processed successfully and sometimes it is getting timeout with message

```
REPORT RequestId: 28e55591-e6a7-4344-b5bc-321bd03422b6 Duration: 900089.03 ms Billed Duration: 900000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 129 MB
```

It can be clearly seen that this a memory issue, but I am not able to understand the root cause. 
It will be great if someone could help me to understand this behavior.

Sometimes it also happens that the lambda is re-triggered and then the file is getting processed.

Comment: What does your memory used look like with the 5mb file?

Comment: It goes around 119 MB

Answer (score 3):

It's due to your use of Panda's dataframe. It uses a lot more memory to store the CSV than what's just the size of the file itself. You can check how much memory the dataframe needs with `df.info(memory_usage='deep')`.

If you just need to convert a csv to json, a better way would be to use the stdlib modules `csv` and `json` and code it yourself.

Comment: Hey @Milan, Thanks for your response . As per your suggestion I have removed the panda library and using `csv` and `json`, but still I am able to process max 17 MB file in 128 MB Lambda. I am still doubting the size it is processing. I mean I was expecting around 30 or 40 MB of data to be processed in this Lambda. It will be great if could share your thoughts on this.

Comment: I think your expectation is correct, 40 MB sounds reasonable. Try processing as much of the data as streams, using `with` statements, etc, to prevent creation of intermediate data structures. Where is the JSON file coming from? S3? And what do you do with the resulting csv file, also upload it to S3?

Comment: Yes Milan , I am downloading file from S3 , converting it and again pushing back it to S3. Thanks for the suggestion let me go through the code once again and see if I can optimize it or make any necessary changes. Will update you soon. 
Thanks for your valuable feedback.